# Laravel unittest failing with no matching handler found for Auth::attempt

Tags: laravel-4, phpunit, mockery

I seem to be running into an issue with my login test with conditions. My login handler checks that the email and password are valid as well as the user being confirmed. The following test cases pass:

```
public function test_redirect_to_login_if_login_fails()
{
    // enable filters to test login
    Route::enableFilters();
    // some fake credentials to use
    $credentials = [
        'email'=>'user@domain.com',
        'password'=>'badpassword',
        'confirmed'=>1
    ];
    // mock the Auth class
    Auth::shouldReceive('attempt')
        ->once()
        ->with($credentials)
        ->andReturn(false);
    // call the login post with the credentials
    $this->call('POST','login',$credentials);
    // assert that we are redirected back to the entry page
    $this->assertRedirectedToRoute('entry');
}

public function test_redirect_if_login_success()
    {
        // enable filtere to test login
        Route::enableFilters();
        // some fake credentials to use
        $credentials = [
            'email'=>'user@domain.com',
            'password'=>'Pa55w0rd',
            'confirmed'=>1
        ];
        // mock the Auth class
        Auth::shouldReceive('attempt')
            ->once()
            ->with($credentials)
            ->andReturn(true);
        // call the login post with the proper credentials
        $response = $this->call('POST','login',$credentials);
        // assert the response is good
        $this->assertTrue($response->isRedirection());
    }
```

This one however, gives me an error - though it's very similar to the first test case above:

```
public function test_redirect_if_user_is_not_confirmed()
    {
        // enable filters to test login
        Route::enableFilters();
        // some fake credentials to use
        $credentials = [
            'email'=>'user@domain.com',
            'password'=>'badpassword',
            'confirmed'=>0
        ];

        // mock the Auth class
        Auth::shouldReceive('attempt')
            ->once()
            ->with($credentials)
            ->andReturn(false);
        // call the login post with the credentials
        $this->call('POST','login',$credentials);
        // assert that we are redirected back to the entry page
        $this->assertRedirectedToRoute('entry');
    }
```

The error:

> Mockery\Exception\NoMatchingExpecationException: No matching handler
>   found for
>   Mockery_0_Illumnate_Auth_AuthManager::attempt(array('email'=>'user@domain.com','password'=>'badpassword','confirmed'=>1,)).
>   Either the method was unexpected or its arguments matched no expected
>   argument list for this method.

My controller method:

```
public function store()
{
    if (Auth::attempt(array("email"=>Input::get('email'),"password"=>Input::get('password'),'confirmed'=>1)))
    {
        return Redirect::intended('home');
    }
    return Redirect::route("entry")->with("danger",Lang::get('orientation.invalid'))->withInput();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test is failing correctly - because your supplying the wrong data to the test.

You have the mock of Auth to receive:

```
Auth::shouldReceive('attempt')
        ->once()
        ->with($credentials)
        ->andReturn(false);
```

Specifically that it should receive `->with($credentials)`. But you have defined `$credentials` as having `confirmed => 0` when your controller is always going to be sending `confirmed => 1` because that is what is hard coded.

Instead - you should still be *expecting* to receive `confirmed => 1` in your test - but mocking a `false` return because no matching record is found.

This should work:

```
// some fake credentials to use
        $credentials = [
            'email'=>'user@domain.com',
            'password'=>'badpassword',
            'confirmed'=>1
        ];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. `confirmed` isn't an input field. The normal flow is that a user registers, gets an email, which will then set a `confirm` column from 0 to 1 in my users table. My understanding from the [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#authenticating-users) (see: Authenticating A User With Conditions) was that if I needed to set other requirements, like a confirmed status, this is how it is done. If this isn't the proper way to do that, do you know the proper way?